# Position of array element

Tags: c

I'm working on program that should find the position of min and max element of array. The code I wrote finds the largest and smallest element but I can't figure out how to find the position it takes in array. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

That is what I have for now:

```
int main ()
{
    int i;
    float a[8] = {
        1.90, 0.75, 3.30, 1.10, 2.00, 4.50, 0.80, 2.50
    }; /* array of ints */

    printf("\nValues are: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("%.2lf\n", a[i]);

    float max = a[0];
    float min = a[0];

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (a[i] > max) {
            max = a[i];
        } else if (a[i] < min) {
            min = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf ("Maximum element in an array : %.2f\n", max);
    printf ("Minimum element in an array : %.2f\n", min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make use of variable to keep the position in a manner similar to what you've done for finding `max` and `min`?

Comment: `float a[8] = { ... }; /* array of ints */`   O_o ??

Comment: I fixed your code indentation. However why your comment says array of ints, when it is array of floats?

Comment: Your `for` loop should start at `i = 1`, since you initialize with the first element.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: you are correct, however it will work as is - but first iteration would be pointless as `a[i] > max` or `a[i] < min` could not be true if `i==0`

Comment: @mvp Of course it will. I'm just pointing it out, because off-by-one errors (and variable initialization, for that matter) are easy to make, and starting it at 1 shows that you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store position ie `i` instead of content of the `a[i]`

```
min=max=0;
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{

  if (a[i] > a[max])
    {

      max = i;
    }

  else if (a[i] < a[min])
    {
      min = i;
    }
```

If you want to print  the minimum and maximum number you can print `a[min]` and `a[max]`

Comment: It comes to compare element position with element value. This is not correct solution

Comment: This is a good idea, but your code is buggy. You should compare, eg, `a[i] > a[max]`.

Comment: oops..sorry :P fixed that

Comment: Note that `min` and `max` are `int`, and they represent the *index* of the minimum and maximum values in the array.

Answer (score 4):

Your program looks pretty good. All you need is to remember indexes of min and max element, like this:

```
 int i_min = 0;
 int i_max = 0;
 if (a[i] > max) {
     max = a[i];
     i_max = i;
 } else if (a[i] < min) {
     min = a[i];
     i_min = i;
 }
```

and then print it.

You can slightly optimize it by storing only indexes of min and max element, but it probably does not matter that much.